# How to avoid part of template from interpolating in angular5?

Tags: angular, templates, interpolation

Let's say i have a component as below:

```
@Component({
  providers: [],
  selector: 'test-component',
  styles: [],
  template: `
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <div class="piece-code">
      <pre>
        <code class="javascript">
        export default class Test {
          say() {
            console.log('hello world')
          }
        }
        </code>
      </pre>
    </div>
    `
})
export class TestComponent {

}
```

Now it is incorrect, because of `{` `}` appears in the template(in `pre > code` block), escape characters like `{`, `}`, `<`, `>` manually would be hard and make the code hard to read & maintain. I am wondering if there is a way to stop angular template engine interpolating the specific area? In my case, it should be `pre > code`?

Answer (score 0):

There is a attribute `ngNonBindable` which you can set to target element to stop angular's interpolation for specific area.

```
<pre ngNonBindable>
  {{ some }}
</pre>
```

But this directive won't help for your situation because single bracket is not considered as interpolation.

---

And for single bracket(`{`, `}`), You can surround them with double bracket like `{{'{'}}` and `{{'}'}}`

```
<pre>
  <code class="javascript">
    export default class Test {{ '{' }}
      say() {{ '{' }}
        console.log('hello world')
      {{ '}' }}
    {{ '}' }}
  </code>
</pre>
```

The other way would be define those code in your component and bind to code element's `innerHTML`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I preferred not using `{{ '{' }}` in my case, that would be too much. 
Anyway, thanks very much, let my think about if there is any other way to organize my code

Comment: @Howard you are welcome! :-) maybe binding to code's `innerHTML` is much more fitter. Any way, good luck!